# How to avoid the repetitions of values when using Sql join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i would like to know how can i avoid the repetitions of values when i'm using SQL join
example:

```
Table: Users
[id]    [name]
1       Bob
2       Junior

Table: images
[id]    [img]       [user_id]
1       water.jpg   1
2       spoon.jpg   2
3       beer.jpg    1
```

---

how can i get these values from the database:

```
id      =>  1
name    =>  Bob
img     =>  [water.jpg, beer.jpg]

id      =>  2 
name    =>  Junior
img     =>  [spoon.jpg]
```

---

Instead of

```
id      =>  1
name    =>  Bob
img     =>  water.jpg 

id      =>  1
name    =>  Bob
img     =>  beer.jpg

id      =>  2
name    =>  Junior
img     =>  spoon.jpg
```

i'm using MySQL what query to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `group by` and `group_concat()`:

```
select u.id, u.name, group_concat(i.img) as imgs
from users u join
     images i
     on u.id = i.user_id
group by u.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
    SELECT users.id, users.name, concat('[',GROUP_CONCAT(images.img SEPARATOR ','),']') as images_concat
    FROM users 
    INNER JOIN images ON (users.id = images.user_id)
    GROUP BY users.id;
```